# Restrict features weights in GradientBoostingClassifier

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, supervised-learning

I am trying to create a classifier from a dataset of ~30 features, using sklearn's `GradientBoostingClassifier`, with 100 estimators and `max_depth=3`.
When I look at the feature importance I see that 2 features catches ~90% of the importance.
Is there a way to restrict the maximal importance of a feature? Of course a loss increase will be necessary.

Comment: Feature importance is something determined with the classifier, it is not a hyperparameter that we could set. If I got the point wrong please add an additional explanation. @David

Comment: @meti But feature importance is something that can be calculated based on the solution. hence, we can insert it to our loss function in such a way that we would penalize for a feature with too much importance.

Comment: There is no easy way to do it, because feature importance is calculated based on a already built tree, so while splitting, the model doesn't know yet which feature has high importance. Could you clarify why you want to reduce impact of the features?

Comment: To diversify the model, some kind of regularization to make sure the decision is made based on different features and not only 2 of them.